# '.../nameidentifier' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I am using Identityserver3 as the authorization server for an MVC application. Therefore, my `Startup` class is like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie();
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
    });
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = "http://localhost:5000/",
        ClientId = "mvc",
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:12262/",
        ResponseType = "id_token",
        UseTokenLifetime = false,
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
    });
}
```

This is my `IdentityUser` subclass:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {

        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", this.Email));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(
            new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider",
                this.Email));

        return userIdentity;
    }

    public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

This is my `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
}
```

But in my `Account/Register` view at the line containing `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` I receive this error:

A claim of type

> 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.

I have seen some questions on SO with the similar problem (maybe not using Identityserver3 anywhere) but their solutions seems not to work, at least the way I'm using them.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I believe the problem is that the claims is not added in the right place. But to confirm this I need some feedback. Are you using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity* (NuGet packages) in connection with Identity Server?
Are you creating the users by code or reading from Database?

For example I used AspNet.Identity with IdentityServer3 and to add a claims for each user you can modify the user service GetClaimsFromAccount method like the folllowing:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IdentityServer3.Core;
using IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration;
using IdentityServer3.Core.Services;

namespace ..... {

public class UserService : AspNetIdentityUserService<IdentityUser, string>
{
    public UserService(UserManager userMgr) : base(userMgr)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim>> GetClaimsFromAccount(IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = (await base.GetClaimsFromAccount(user)).ToList();

        // to make sure the email is in the claims
        if (claims.Any(c=>c.Type == Constants.ClaimTypes.Email) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email))
        {
            claims.Add(.....);
        }

        return claims;
    }
}
....
}
```

Notice that identityServer3.core comes with constants containing the claims type (Constants.Claimtypes.Email).

Hope this helps a little :)